# Interesting DSLs, Implemented in Scala?

Tags: scala, dsl

I've seen [BASIC](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1403) and [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/scala-dsl.html) DSLs in Scala, and they're just fantastic. Any more examples of such DSLs?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a good source in the MEAP (Early Access) book
[image: Gosh Cover]
[**DSL in action**](http://manning.com/ghosh/) from Debasish Ghosh (blog: "[Ruminations of a programmer](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/))

Testing frameworks like [scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/) are classic examples of DSL:

```
  test("pop is invoked on an empty stack") {     
    val emptyStack = new Stack[String]
    evaluating { emptyStack.pop() } should produce [NoSuchElementException]
    emptyStack should be ('empty)
  }
```

There are many others DSL-based frameworks out there:

- [specs](http://code.google.com/p/specs/): "Behaviour-Driven-Design  framework"
- [internal DSLs](http://pragmaticdesign.blogspot.com/2009/04/scala-program-like-you-mean-it.html)
- [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/): "A Scala ORM and DSL for talking with Databases with minimum verbosity and maximum type safety"

```
    def songCountByArtistId: Query[GroupWithMeasures[Long,Long]] =
      from(artists, songs)((a,s) =>
        where(a.id === s.artistId)
        groupBy(a.id)
        compute(count)
      )
```

Comment: Really good book. Also includes other languages so you can compare how DSLs feel in different languages.

Comment: Excellent book. Mr. Ghosh covers Scala especially well (that's the part I read). Also, you may want to read Mr. Spiewak's educational, well-written post on Parser Combinators (critical to external Scala DSLs) - www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-magic-behind-parser-combinators

Answer (score 6):

lift-json provides a DSL to generate JSON. For example the following DSL:

```
("person" ->
  ("name" -> "Joe") ~
  ("age" -> 35) ~
  ("spouse" ->
    ("person" ->
      ("name" -> "Marilyn") ~
      ("age" -> 33)
    )
  )
)
```

creates the following JSON:

```
{ 
  "person": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 35,
    "spouse": {
      "person": {
        "name": "Marilyn",
        "age": 33
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[ScalaModules](http://wiki.github.com/weiglewilczek/scalamodules/) is a DSL for working with [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage).

Another one is available with [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/scala-dsl.html) a platform for enterprise integration.

[Scala-Query](http://github.com/szeiger/scala-query) and [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/) also provide DSLs for querying databases among other things.

[ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) is also an awesome example of what is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Two good examples are the built-in DSLs for Parser Combinators and Actors. There is a SQL wrapper called DBC (not yet ready), here you can see how it looks like: http://scala.sygneca.com/libs/dbc

Answer (score 1):

[XML in Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/131) is another example.

Answer (score 0):

The ScalaQL paper [(PDF)](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~dspiewak/papers/scalaql.pdf) describes the implementation of an interesting DSL for language integrated database queries.

Answer (score 0):

And then there's Foursquare's Rogue  http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/01/21/rogue-a-type-safe-scala-dsl-for-querying-mongodb/