# DSLs(Domain Specific Programming Languages) implemented using different GPLs(General Purpose Programming Languages)

Tags: dsl-tools, dsl

I am looking for DSLs implemented using general purpose programming languages(GPLs) e.g., C#, Java , Scala and so on.  Primary goal is to survey various important attributes of well-designed DSL implementations used in a daily basis in Software Industry.

I would highly appreciate if you could point me out such DSL implementations (examples or repositories) and state your reasons why you consider it to be a good DSL.

Thank you,

Adil Akhter

---

***EDIT 1:***

IMHO, this post can contribute to create a listing of interesting prevailing DSLs used extensively in today’s Software Development (after searching, at least I could not find any such listings covering all the GPLs).

One of the several inherent benefits of this listing – it can be used create taxonomy of the DSLs and domain they are targeting to.

Followings are the related links that describes some interesting DSLs and Tools:

**DSLs**( categorized by GPLs):

1. **Ruby** DSLs  => [Ruby DSL (Domain Specific Language) repositories, examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899665/ruby-dsl-domain-specific-language-repositories-examples)
2. **Clojure** DSLs => [Are there any Clojure DSLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968055/are-there-any-clojure-dsls)
3. **Scala** DSLs =>  [Interesting DSLs, Implemented in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186783/interesting-dsls-implemented-in-scala)
4. **C#** DSLs => SharpDOM ( http://sharpdom.codeplex.com )

**Tools:**

1. Microsoft Visual Studio Visualization and Modeling SDK : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at boost.spirit2 to find a very complex DSL in a mainstream language. Otherwise you could look at any dialect of lisp which makes it very easy to write DSLs and so you will find lots of them.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [non-procedural techniques for implementing DSLs, such as (our) program transformation system](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DomainSpecificLanguage.html).  I think you will find them surprisingly powerful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am quite a big fan of your work. I am currently working with [Stratego](http://strategoxt.org/), a program transformation system that uses strategic term rewriting. 

However, the primary objective of this question was to find out how and what kind of DSLs(or Little Languages) have been implemented to solve real world programming problems and how successful/viable they are. With Regards

Comment: You should check out: SQL, Relay Ladder Logic, Constraint Languages, HDLS (Verilog, VHDL), HTML, XML, Prolog, and of course languages used to build language tools (EBNF, attribute grammars, ...) ... These are all very widely used DSLs. What makes them useful as I see it is they enable the succinct description of certain tasks and/or offer different models of computation than our classic procedural (including OO) languages do. One of the best DSLs ever invented is the Calculus, used by every serious engineer on the planet; it is a constraint system operating on formulas.

Comment: Thanks again. I will look into these DSLs. With regards

Comment: Prolog is definitely not a DSL, it is a general purpose language built around a strong logic paradigm. I am also not 100% convinced that SQL is a DSL considering it is a database interface and used in a virtually unlimited number of domains.