# What are the open source scala-based DSL projects out there?

Tags: scala, dsl

I am currently looking for open source scala projects to work on. Can anyone provide a list of open source scala-based DSL projects out there?

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186783/interesting-dsls-implemented-in-scala?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also have a look at [the wikis tools and libraries](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries) section, many open source projects are present.  Most will have syntactic niceties in them, I'm biased of course but I'd also recommend [Scales](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml) ([current documentation](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.2/0.3-RC7/index.html)) to look at - I believe its a recognisable approach for all that know XPath or builder approaches.