# Creating a "container" for an DSL

Tags: scala, dsl

I am trying to create a kind of main container for my DSL, something like:

```
val mod_a = module ("file1.scala") {
       //the elements defined using the dsl....
}

val mod_b = module("className") {
       // the elements defined using the dsl...
}

val mod_c = ....
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607279/scala-dsl-nested-block-referencing-parent) and actually I was trying in the same way but it's not my case :(. I mean, maybe the parenthesis should be "`{}`" instead of "`()`".

Any suggestion how I can do it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know "package objects"?

Comment: @michaJIS , Yes, but how you mean to use them in my case? I updated a little my question, also!

Comment: How about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186783/interesting-dsls-implemented-in-scala?rq=1)?

Comment: @Sergey , Thanks for this rich set of references! Actually, I am going through the example in the book of D.Ghosh - still not lucky to understand how I can resolve my case. I am trying to dig in the `scalaTest DSL`, I am hopping to understand its implementation in a reasonable time!